# Create object from Viewholder in Adapter class with context from Activity - no value passed for 'context'

Tags: android, kotlin

I've really tried lots of things and read tons of articles on the Internet before making the decision to ask a question here. So please forgive me if this is question seems to be quite simple for someone out there, but I'm very new in the android development and I really can't go further on this. I got this project from a co-worker of mine, after he left the company, so getting started with Android Studio and Kotlin on this way wasn't very beginner-friendly for me.

Here's my problem:

I have an adapter class with a ViewHolder inside it. So, when the user performs a long click on a data entry, a new Activity should start. Therefore, I extended the adapter class with a context variable, to be able to get the context from the View.

For the sake of clearness, I'm posting only the relevant parts of the code.

```
class PositionAdapter(
    private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater,
    private val listener: OnPositionAdapterListener,
    private var context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), StickyHeaderInterface {
    // this is not the complete code 

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_HEADER -> {
                val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.wepos_header, p0, false)
                PositionHeaderViewHolder(itemView)
            }
            else -> {
                val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.wepos_item, p0, false)
                context = itemView.context
                return PositionViewHolder(itemView)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

        if (holder is PositionHeaderViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(positionsList[p1], listener, p1)
        } else if (holder is PositionViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(positionsList[p1], listener, p1, selectedPos == p1)
        }
    }

inner class PositionViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(wePos: WePos, listener: OnPositionAdapterListener, p1: Int, isSelected: Boolean) {

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
                selectedPos = adapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
                listener.onPositionClicked(wePos.lfdNr.toInt())
            }
       itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
                selectedPos = adapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
                listener.onPositionLongClicked(wePos.lfdNr.toInt())
                true
            }
       val intent = Intent(context, StorageGoodsActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
  }
}
```

My problem appears in the method where an object from the adapter class should be created. The adapter provides data in the **SupplierActivity** and from here I would like to start the **StorageGoodsActivity** when the user performs a long click on a data entry. I have to get the context of the **SupplierActivity** somehow, unfortunatelly all of my tries failed so far.

```
internal fun SupplierActivity.initPositionList() {
    rv_position.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rv_position.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

    positionAdapter = PositionAdapter(this.layoutInflater, object : OnPositionAdapterListener, /**context**/ {

        override fun onPositionClicked(wenr: Int) {}
        override fun onPositionLongClicked(wenr: Int) {}
    })
    rv_position.adapter = positionAdapter
    rv_position.addItemDecoration(HeaderDecoration(rv_head, positionAdapter))
}
```

I tried with `SupplierActivity.this`, with the hope that I could get the context from the Activity, I tried with creating methods that could possibly return the Activity context and so on... Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can just write:

```
internal fun SupplierActivity.initPositionList() {
    rv_position.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rv_position.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

    positionAdapter = PositionAdapter(this.layoutInflater, object : OnPositionAdapterListener {
        override fun onPositionClicked(wenr: Int) {}
        override fun onPositionLongClicked(wenr: Int) {}
    }, this)
    rv_position.adapter = positionAdapter
    rv_position.addItemDecoration(HeaderDecoration(rv_head, positionAdapter))
}
```

Comment: this was very fast response and as it seems it was very easy to solve. Thank you @Andrei Tanana